# should react web and react-native share package.json?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

We are about to develop both react web/ react native for same service.
I guess there could be a lot of common stuff.

Especially, should we keep our package.json for the two platforms separate or combined?

Answer (score 1):

You can share the same package.json but I wouldn't recommend it.

There will eventually be a time when your applications won't have the same version, or the same repository and having two packages makes it clearer.

The scripts will also have to be duplicated (or at least have other names).

Finally, you'll run into packagers issues. Check [this article](http://jkaufman.io/react-web-native-codesharing/) and the comments for more input on this.

**Bottom line ==> bad practice**, I wouldn't recommend it. I could work for a time but I think you'll run into issues very soon.